# python change order of month and day in date format

Tags: python

I have a column that displays date as
2016/26/2 (d/m/y)

How can i display it as 2/26/2016 (m/d/y)?

```
[in] print(nir['Date'])
[out] 0    2005-01-12
      1    2006-01-03
      2    2006-01-06
      3    2006-01-09
      4    2006-01-12
      5    2007-01-03
      6    2007-01-06
      7    2007-01-09
      8    2007-01-12
```

i tried to do this:

```
      nir.Date = ['{}-{}-{}'.format(m,d,y) for y, m, d in map(lambda x: str(x).split('-'), nir.Date)]
```

but no luck...
is there any way to easily swap places of month and day without converting to strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `python/pandas` it is not possible if dont want convert to strings.

For strings use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [formats](http://strftime.org/):

```
nir.Date = nir.Date.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But as i understand, this code does not change the place of values, it just converts it to string. This can also be suitable if i can change the place of %m and %d value. 
I tried to swap places in your code but no result...

Comment: Do you think `('%d/%m/%Y')` ?

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong
('%m/%d/%Y')
and 
('%d/%m/%Y')
gave different results.
Good! it works!